# How do I stop an NSSet from being mutated while it's being enumerated elsewhere?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, enumeration

I have an `NSMutableSet` of objects which I mutate at several points on the main thread. There are times though when this set will be enumerated on a background thread. Short of using a bunch of booleans to manage state, is there a good way to make any mutations wait, should the set currently be enumerating?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableSet` is not thread safe. You cannot hack it to be thread safe.

If you want a copy that won't mutate for inspection in the background then take a `copy` on the main queue and pass that back. It'll be a lot faster than any other approach.

Otherwise you'll have to wrap all accesses to it in a mutex. `@synchronize`ing on the set itself would be the most straightforward way.

Comment: But note that you can't, in general, use "fast enumeration" on a mutated object, even if individual enumeration operations are protected by a lock.  Some form of explicit enumeration must be used, or the duration of the entire "fast enumeration" loop must locked.